# Clean URL not working

Tags: 8

I have downloaded Drupal 8.x-dev at https://drupal.org/node/572834 to test on my local PC (Xubuntu 14.04 Beta 1).

I have successfully installed but when I try to access Admin menu is giving me "Not Found" pages, though on a simplytest.me sandbox it working ok.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and it belongs to superuser.com

Comment: Oscar post your solution as an answer

Comment: @Bala, I've posted as you requested :)

Comment: @chx why would it?

Comment: Because the ways to enable mod rewrite has nothing to do with Drupal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @tenken for giving me a hint this was related to "clean urls" issue.

I got this working with the following steps:

1. Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` # Enabling "rewrite" module
2. In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and look at the block `<Directory /var/www/>` changed from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`
3. Run `sudo service apache2 restart`

This reference was helpful https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Comment: thank you. I was getting really down hearted with my 1st try to use D8. `AllowOverride All` in `<Directory /var/www/>` allowed login. Was stuck with just Front Page until now!

Comment: I have already enabled rewrite module, and gave  AllowOverride All, but still i face the same issue even after apache restart...any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the paged you linked is actually a `-dev` release from like 2013.

A page that lists the recent releases can be found here:
https://drupal.org/node/3060/release

I recommend installing the:

[drupal 8.0-alpha9](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-8.0-alpha9.tar.gz), Posted by catch on February 19, 2014 at 2:29am

Keep in mind that Drupal8 prior to I believe any `Beta` release is not officially supported by any upgrade path (to my knowledge). If you're a programmer and not a casual site administrator or user; code you write may be affected/break as Drupal8 matures to a release candidate.

Somebody please correct me if I got the `Supported` version wrong (even for just  developers from an API standpoint; I know like the new Migrate API is still unstable).

**EDIT:**

After commentary, it turns out ModRewrite needed to be enabled on Apache for these paths to work without a querystring parameter.

Comment: If you follow the link I posted it shows "Last updated: March 4, 2014 - 23:58". I have tried to install drupal-8.0-alpha9.tar.gz but the results same...

Comment: That "last updated flag" may be for the node and not the file. It's interesting you have that problem on 8.0-alpha9 ... because I also have it installed and do not see that error. Perhaps it's "user error" :)

Comment: does your apache install allow for 'clean urls'?

Comment: To allow "clean urls", if I'm not mistaken, I have to run "sudo a2enmod rewrite". I haven't done it when I was posting this thread.

Comment: I see the core modules had been installed, it's just not showing up them. As you mentioned, this can be related to "clean urls". In drupal 7 allowing clean urls can be done in configuration. But it's not showing up for drupal 8 dev.

Comment: Thanks for hint regarding "clean urls". Can you please update your answer with it and I will accept so that it will be helpful for other people?

Comment: I added an EDIT section to my reply summarizing our comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem where I would go to my-site.com/admin/what-ever-page, I would get an error.

I made sure that the AllowOverride All was set.

Also made sure that the rewrite module was installed and enabled.

Still had the issue.

What I found was that cURL had not been installed. Once that was in place and the server was restarted, the */admin/* pages started working.

Comment: i still face this issue even after curl is enabled...any suggestion/.